# Angular component to count the number of viewed element in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular

I have a requirement to display an Angular 4 component which contains a counter for the number of current viewed page for a specific table, this counter can be 
incremented or decreased in real time.

Could you please give me some hints in order to implement this.
Technology: Angular 4, C# and Sql server database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Forget about angular for a minute and just think about how you're going to get the data to the client. How real time does it actually have to be? Of course, since you're using angular, rxjs may be a good approach, considering that you already depend on it, but it is important not to think about it in the context of displaying the data but rather retrieving the data.

Comment: Also this question is not really clear about the requirements. Also looking at your comment on the other answer I have no idea what you mean. Please provide some clarification about what you mean by "currently viewed element of a specific table"

Answer (score 1):

you for this kind of senario you can make use of "[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)" library provided by microsoft.

**What can you do with ASP.NET SignalR?**

SignalR can be used to add any sort of "real-time" web functionality to your web application. While chat is often used as an example, you can do a whole lot more. Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for using SignalR.

It also enables completely new types of applications, that require high frequency updates from the server, e.g. real-time gaming.

Example : [Introduction to SignalR](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590660/Introduction-to-SignalR)

---

Not expert on Angular js 2 by as per me you need to implement `OnInit` interface avilalbe in angular js 2

```
class AppElement implements OnInit {

  void ngOnInit() {
    alert('Visited');
    //use httpclient object to insert value
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, how to trace a page in Angular SPA context  was visited and log this info in database?

Comment: I like the idea of using signal R for this but the question isn't specific enough to actually answer in a meaningful way.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - he askd about real time update , right and if you have two client open at same time and want to update count at both than SignalR is only solution....

Comment: I need to log the viewed page count in table and according to that  number of views, I will display the total count  in dashboard.

Comment: @PranayRana no it's not the only option but it's a good option. Other options include polling and websockets. Polling is used to polyfill websockets and SignalR is, IIRC, implemented on top of websockets.

Comment: could you please provide me  a startup example for IIRC, is there any native typescript api which I can use with Angular.